# Building PJSip for iOS + Support g729 codec

Tags: ios, objective-c, pjsip

I've got an old app that uses PJSIP and needs to be upgraded.

I need help with **adding support for g729 codec, for every architecture**.

I would like to know the exact steps I need to perform so I'll have a well compiled pj build + g729 support.

I managed to understand to building part and the lipo part.

There are two ways to add g729 support:

1. Adding open source codec files and address to them in JP building - would be happy to hear about this option - I already have the codec files. Need to know how to make them fit different architectures and the lines I need to add to JP library (and where, guess in the JPMediaCodec area).
2. Adding build-in support (couldn't manage to understand and use IPP, tools, requirements etc.)

Comment: what's the error/problem exactly you receive when building libs ?

Comment: @azimov please see my edited questions for more precise details.

Comment: have you tried this https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Intel_IPP_Codecs ?

Comment: @azimov Yup, didn't manage to make it work. That's why I need help.. ;)

Comment: Can't help you right now, but if you won't managed to work it, I will create a small tutorial, later.

Comment: @azimov 10x alot! If so, post it as an answer.

Comment: @azimov anytime for help? Re-edit the question.

Comment: @MatanGold, Even I'm looking for the help for integrating G729 codec into my pjsip library. Please let me know if you have solved it.

Comment: @MdRais Sorry, but we eventually gave up on adding g729 support...